# What's the cleanest way to add a blank line after a section of a Mustache template?

Tags: mustache

Let's say I want to render multiple collections in a Mustache template. I might have this:

```
some header content

{{#foos}}
some foo content
{{/foos}}

{{#bars}}
some bar content
{{/bars}}

some footer content
```

Now, supposing `foos` and `bars` above are both non-empty, then everything will look fine. But if `foos` is empty, for example, I'll see two blank lines after "some header content", which is ugly. On the other hand, if I omit the blank line between the `foos` and `bars` sections, then when both collections are non-empty there will be no break between them, which is also ugly.

Here's one solution that I think would work:

```
some header content

{{#foos}}
some foo content
{{/foos}}
{{#flag_that_foos_not_empty}}

{{/flag_that_foos_not_empty}}
{{#bars}}
some bar content
{{/bars}}

some footer content
```

But then the *template* is ugly.

Is there any clean way to achieve what I'm after here: inserting a line break at the end of a collection, only if the collection is non-empty?

To be clear: I realize this would be a pretty ridiculous thing to worry about if I were generating text for computer consumption, like HTML. In this case I'm attempting to use Mustache to generate some human-readable content, where attractive presentation of the content is important.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the trick, and not be as ugly, IMO:

```
some header content

{{# has_foos }}
{{# foos }}
some foo content
{{/ foos }}

{{/ has_foos }}
{{# has_bars }}
{{# bars }}
some bar content
{{/ bars }}

{{/ has_bars }}
some footer content
```

Depending on your Mustache implementation, you might be able to replace those "has" tags with `{{# foos.length }}`.